# Windows wont boot when external HDD not connected, how can I fix this?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, external-hdd

My current system is Windows 8.1 Pro with Media Center.

I wanted to try Ubuntu 14.04, and therefore I installed Ubuntu on an External HDD. (I followed some steps that I found on the internet)

After I installed Ubuntu 14.04, the Grub worked fine for Ubuntu, but when I wanted to boot back to my Windows 8.1 I would get the Grub error:

"GNU GRUB Version 2.02~ beta 2-9

```
    [Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported
    For the first world, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists the possible completions of a device/filename]
    grub>"
```

I thought to myself, did I ruin my Windows? I frantically looked up a temporary fix in which I found one called Boot Repair Disk. (Now a quick reminder, Ubuntu still works properly in the External HDD and I can still fully access it.) So I run Boot Repair Disk and I let it do it's thing, after that, I try to boot Windows 8.1 without my External HDD and it WILL NOT boot. So I plug my External HDD into the USB and let the Grub run, I then select run Windows 8.1 in the Grub Menu and it will run.

My Question: Can I get Windows 8.1 to run WITHOUT the External HDD plugged into the USB? I believe that the Ubuntu Grub is using my External HDD to run the Grub menu. How can I fix this? Please help! Much appreciation!

Comment: This is about Ubuntu/grub so I think it's off topic.

Comment: Post link to Boot info report that Boot-Repair gives you. If you say external drive is external drive usually Boot-Repair fixes it. But not sure it that works correctly if Windows 8 and UEFI on internal drive. Is external drive also UEFI boot? Report will show that.

Answer (score 0):

You say:

```
I believe that the Ubuntu Grub is using my External HDD to run the Grub menu
```

Yes, it is indeed.

The Grub 2 user-configurable settings are contained mainly in /etc/default/grub.

The files in /etc/grub.d.

And when update-grub is executed the results are input into the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file.

How can You fix this?

Test this:

Boot into the Windows 8.1 with Your external HDD plug into usb.

Unplug Your external HDD.

Open the Command Prompt

Run it:

```
bcdedit /set {default} device partition=c:
bcdedit /set {default} osdevice partition=c:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} device partition=c:
```

Now, Ubuntu wont boot, only boot Windows.

Download EasyBCD, latest build from here:

http://neosmart.net/forums/showthread.php?t=642

Install Easy BCD and then run it

Click External Devices, then external HDD

Browse to the path of the /boot

Give it a name, then click Create Entry.

Next time you boot you will have the option of booting to your External HDD.